# como llenar un select a partir de una fecha seleccionada?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, sql-server

tengo el siguiente inconveniente, paso a dejarle los codigos de lo que estoy haciendo,

FORMULARIO

```
<form action="#" method="post" name="target">
<table class="table table-sm text-center" style="margin:auto; width:30%">
    <tr>
      <th>Desde</th>
      <th>Hasta</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <div id="picker"></div>
      <td><input name="dFec" id="dFec" readonly="readonly" style="text-align:center"></td>
      <div id="picker1"></div>
      <td><input name="hFec" id="hFec" readonly="readonly" style="text-align:center"></td>
     </tr>
    <div id="other">
      </div>
</table>
<h5 class="h3 font-weight-normal text-center">Usuario</h5>
    <div class="form-group text-center">
        <select name="usuario" id="usuario" class="form-control form-control-sm" style="width:35%; margin:auto;"></select>
    </div>
<div class="form-group text-center">
<input class="btn btn-primary btn-md" type="submit" id="enviar" name="enviar" value="Mostrar" style="margin-top:15px;"/>
                </div>
</form>
</div>
         </div>
         </div>
```

SCRIPT

```
<script language="javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#dFec").change(function () {

                    
                    $("#dFec option:selected").each(function () {
                        fechaDesde = $(this).val();
                        $.post("getUsuario.php", { fechaDesde : fechaDesde }, function(data){
                            $("#usuario").html(data);
                        });            
                    });
                })
            });

$(document).ready(function(){
                $("#hFec").change(function () {
                    
                    $("#hFec option:selected").each(function () {
                        fechaHasta = $(this).val();
                        $.post("getUsuario.php", { fechaHasta : fechaHasta }, function(data){
                            $("#usuario").html(data);
                        });            
                    });
                })
            });
```

getUsuario.php

```
$conn = conectar();
$dFec = $_POST['dFec'];
$hFec = $_POST['hFec'];

$query ="select usuario from sucursales where fecha between $dFec and $hFec and id_sucursal = '3'";
$resultado = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $query);

while ($rowB = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $resultado, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $html.= "<option value='".$rowB['usuario']."'>".$rowB['usuario']."</option>";
    }
    echo $html;
```

[image: muestra]

Hago la aclaracion que el id_sucursal esta puesto a mano a proposito para realizar pruebas, mas adelante tendría que general otro select donde levante también dinámicamente el id de la sucursal. También digo que esto mismo lo tengo implementado en otras paginas sin datepicker y funciona a la perfección, llenándose los select de manera dinámica. Estimo que aquí el problema esta en que el datepicker esta dentro de un input y las funciones javascript pasan los valores de un select, nose como hacer para pasar el valor sin que sea un select ya que si cambio el input por el select ni siquiera muestra el calendario. Si alguno me puede dar una mano, les agradezco mucho. Saludos

Comment: Saludos. Te sugiero verificar lo siguiente (no necesario en orden mencionado): * Tanto para `$("#dFec").change(...);` como  `$("#hFec").change(...)` envías como parámetro `fechaDesde` y `fechaHasta ` en el php "esperas" `dFec` y `hFec`. * Antes de invocar el `$.post` verifiques que el "otro" componente con fecha tenga dato (y que este sea válido). * Que en el **.php** `$dFec` y `$hFec` tengan información/formato válido(a) ya que lo pasas directo para generar el **SQL** o sino incluir la conversión respectiva. * Antes del `while` inicializar `$html` como cadena vacía.

Comment: Hola Roberto, primeramente gracias por tu comentario, cambie lo que me dijiste, cambie "fechaDesde" por dFec y fechaHasta por hFec, lo otro que me decis de la fecha, eso tambien lo cambie por el formato de fecha que va al sql, el problema es que nunca llega por post la fecha a getUsuario, hice un var_dump y llega un array vacio, por lo tanto la query nunca se ejecuta y por ende no se llena el select de usuario. Avisame si puedo probar otra cosa.